# Getting match of Group with Asterisk?

Tags: java, regex, string, capturing-group

How can I get the content for a group with an asterisk?

For example I'd like to pare a comma separated list, e. g. `1,2,3,4,5`.

```
private static final String LIST_REGEX = "^(\\d+)(,\\d+)*$";
private static final Pattern LIST_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(LIST_REGEX);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String list = "1,2,3,4,5";
    final Matcher matcher = LIST_PATTERN.matcher(list);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
    for (int i = 0, n = matcher.groupCount(); i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
true
0   1,2,3,4,5
1   1
```

How can I get every single entry, i. e. `1`, `2`, `3`, ...?

I am searching for a common solution. This is only a demonstrative example.
Please imagine a more complicated regex like `^\\[(\\d+)(,\\d+)*\\]$` to match a list like `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: For your second example the easiest should be to maybe use regex to get what is between [] and after use split. It will be really less efficient to use regex for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `String.split()`.

```
for (String segment : "1,2,3,4,5".split(","))
    System.out.println(segment);
```

Or you can repeatedly capture with assertion:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d),?");
for (Matcher m = pattern.matcher("1,2,3,4,5");; m.find())
     m.group(1);
```

For your second example you added you can do a similar match.

```
for (String segment : "!!!!![1,2,3,4,5] //"
                          .replaceFirst("^\\D*(\\d(?:,\\d+)*)\\D*$", "$1")
                          .split(","))
    System.out.println(segment);
```

I made an [online code demo](http://ideone.com/rXMZ20). I hope this is what you wanted.

---

> how can I get all the matches (zero, one or more) for a arbitary group with an asterisk `(xyz)*`? *[The group is repeated and I would like to get every repeated capture.]*

No, you cannot. [Regex Capture Groups and Back-References](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) tells why:

> #### The Returned Value for a Given Group is the Last One Captured
>
> Since a capture group with a quantifier holds on to its number, what value does the engine return when you inspect the group? **All engines return the last value captured.** For instance, if you match the string *`A_B_C_D_`* with `([A-Z]_)+`, when you inspect the match, Group 1 will be *`D_`*. With the exception of the .NET engine, all intermediate values are lost. **In essence, Group 1 gets overwritten each time its pattern is matched.**

Comment: Thanks. For this example is your solution the easiest way, but this is more a common question.

Comment: @Vertex What's the common question? Is it that you want to match digits between commas from a list, or you want to match all digits?

Comment: the common question is how to deal with groups that have an asterisk: `(xyz)*`? The definition says, that the regex `xyz` can appears zero, one or more times. And I'd like to get all the matches. In the _special_ list example above that means, I want to get all these matches: `1`, `2`, `3`,... for `(,\\d+)*`. I voted +1 because other people may search for this _special_ problem, but I'am not :)

Comment: @Vertex You cannot neutralize the quantifier into capturing. When capturing groups are repeated in a match, only the last match will be remembered. I'm going to update my answer and explain how this is so.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you may be looking for something like the following, this will handle both of your examples.

```
private static final String LIST_REGEX = "^\\[?(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)\\]?$";
private static final Pattern LIST_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(LIST_REGEX);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String list = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
    final Matcher matcher = LIST_PATTERN.matcher(list);

    matcher.find(); 
    int i = 0;

    String[] vals = matcher.group(1).split(",");

    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
    System.out.println(i + "\t" + matcher.group(1));

    for (String x : vals) {
       i++;
       System.out.println(i + "\t" + x);
    }
}
```

Output

```
true
0   1,2,3,4,5
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

Comment: I voted +1 because other people may search for this special problem and you solution for it. But I don't accept the answer because I want to know how can I get all the matches (zero, one or more) for a arbitary group with an asterisk `(xyz)*`