# Java: Extracting multiple values from a String using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract VALUE1, VALUE2 and VALUE3 from the following multi-line string:

```
String input = "aa a\r\na aa \r\na getString(\"VALUE1\");aagetInt(\"VALUE2\");aa\r\n a getString(\"VALUE3\"); aaa\r\naaa";
```

I've tried:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(\\S+)\"+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

But this produces:

```
VALUE1\");aagetInt(\"VALUE2\");aa\r\n a getString(\"VALUE3
```

It takes everything between the first and last quotation marks.

Then I've tried this one:

```
"(.*)get(\\S+)\\(\"(\\S+)\"(.*)"
```

But this only takes the last match, VALUE3 (with matcher.group(3)).

How can I get all 3 values: VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3?

Comment: use `Pattern.compile("\"([^\"])\"")`. Please note that this gets way more difficult if the real values of `VALUE1` etc are allowed to contain a `"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting match of Group with Asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858345/getting-match-of-group-with-asterisk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\S+` matches all non whitespace chars, and using `.*` matches to the end of the line first, so in both pattern you are matching too much.

Getting the value in parenthesis that starts with `get` and using non greedy `\S+?` (note that is does not match spaces):

```
get[^\s()]*\("(\S+?)"\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AcU01c/1)

Example:

```
String input = "aa a\r\na aa \r\na getString(\"VALUE1\");aagetInt(\"VALUE2\");aa\r\n a getString(\"VALUE3\"); aaa\r\naaa";
String regex = "get[^\\s()]*\\(\"(\\S+?)\"\\)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));            
}
```

Output

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern was slightly off.  Use this version:

```java
String input = "aa a\r\na aa \r\na getString(\"VALUE1\");aagetInt(\"VALUE2\");aa\r\n a getString(\"VALUE3\"); aaa\r\naaa";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\(\"(.*?)\"\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

This prints:

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
```